# putty output screen too small?

Tags: putty, display

I'm having strange problem with my putty console. I'm establishing connection over ssh to my home computer [ windows 7 + freesshd server ]. Everything works just fine, but I'm getting this tiny screen with output, I can resize it of course, but the content is still in small box [ content doesn't resize ]
I've tried to change the number of columns and rows in properties, but it didn't change anything. The same thing is with cygwin client.

Comment: Which font is Putty configured to use?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Windows version of putty you can have the font size change or the number of rows/columns change when the window is resized: under `Window` there is a `When window size is resized` section.
[image: putty resize setting screenshot]

If you're using *nix you may have to use `wine` to run the Windows version to get this feature of putty.

Comment: it doesn't work, I've tried it as well, but still thank you for support :)

Comment: @iie: Also check the font settings in the category `Appearance`.